# multiple clickable timestamps for long audio-files

Tags: javascript, user-controls, html5-audio

**Dear Stackoverflow  Participants!**

I need a code-template for a user-friendly audio-controls solution: I want to use **several clickable timestamps** (buttons) to increase the accessibility of long mp3-files (interviews for qualitative social-research purposes).

Which changes are necessary to make the example below work?

best regards

manuelito123

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
<source src="https://ia801309.us.archive.org/5/items/eubanks_elizabeth_01/eubanks_elizabeth_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<p></p>
<button onclick="getCurTime()" type="button">Get current time position</button><br>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 5 seconds</button><br> 
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 03:30 minutes</button><br>
<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Set time position to 11:05 minutes</button><br>

<script>
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function getCurTime() { 
    alert(aud.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
aud.currentTime=5;
} 

var y = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function getCurTime() { 
    alert(y.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
    y.currentTime=210;
} 

var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function getCurTime() { 
    alert(x.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
    x.currentTime = 665;
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is now online here: [DEMO](http://0999.at/a/test3.html)

The communication between audio-player and buttons works perfectly, but there is a problem with the browsers. The audio-file starts in dependence of the browser from different points of the audio-file. If I press e.g. the button 03:30 in firefox, the audio-player shows 3:30 - the same in IE11 - the start point should be the same. But de facto it isn't: When you listen to the file you hear, that the content isn't identical in different browsers.

best regards, manuelito123